# swapping elements of a 2 dimensional vector c++

Tags: vector, swap

I have a matrix of the form

```
    vector<vector<int>> K
```

which has size **NxN**. How can i **swap** two elements of this vector say  **K[i]k[j]** with **K[n-j][i]**?
In general, how can i swap two elements of an 2D vector?

Answer (score 0):

Because vector's [] operator returns a reference, a std::swap() will work.  For example:

```
swap(K[i][j], K[n-i][i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The general swapping could look something like this

```
void swap(int& a, int& b)
{
   int temp = a;
   a = b;
   b = tmp;
}
```

Then you call it with

```
swap(K[i][j], K[n - j][i]);
```

Or you can just call std::swap as [@Jeffrey](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38836286/6179296) suggests